# MonoDevelop: How can I make fields marks with an attribute display on a single line?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop 4.x for Unity. When I mark a field with an attribute i.e.:

```
[SerializeField] bool myBool;
```

Mono ends reformatting it as:

```
[SerializeField]
   bool
          myBool;
```

How can I make it display all on one line?

Comment: Turn the reformatting off... I hate it and would slow me down even more because I was trying to rectify the false formatting.

Comment: How do I turn off reformatting? I still want my code to be formatted btw.

Comment: I'm not at my computer atm but I'm pretty sure you can customize what gets formatted. Search google

Comment: Sadly it seems @Sadlon's first suggestion is the only way to get rid of this newline.  Of course that's not really an option, sacrificing autoformatting everywhere to get it the way you want it in one specific situation. It seems to be a MonoDevelop bug. See [this discussion](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/code-formatting-of-c-field-attributes.211665/) for example.